# ReactJS center "Sign in with Google" button

Tags: reactjs

I am using Google to log in users. I want to center the button on my website login.

The button is rendered by this command in my Login.js:

```
google.accounts.id.renderButton(
    document.getElementById("sign_in_button_google_inner"),
    { theme: "outline", size: "large" }
)
```

I have tried to center it by moving the button into a wrapper, and calling the button inner:

```
<div id="sign_in_form_google">
    <p>Use Google to login below.</p>
    <div id="sign_in_button_google_wrapper">
        <div id="sign_in_button_google_inner"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then styling it like this:

**Login.css**

```
div.sign_in_button_google_wrapper{
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align:center;
}
div.sign_in_button_google_inner{

}
```

However this doesnt help.

This is how it looks:

[image]

This is how I want it:

[image]

**Login.js**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import './Login.css';
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode"

const google = window.google;

export default function Login({ setToken }) {

  // Handle response from Google login
  async function handleCallbackResponse(response){
    // console.log("Google token: " + response.credential)
    var userObject = jwt_decode(response.credential)
    var userEmail = userObject.email;
    // console.log("userEmail=" + userEmail)
    document.getElementById("sign_in_form_google").hidden = true;

    
    document.getElementById("feedback_div").hidden = false;

    // Call login on backend async
    const backendToken = await loginBackend(response.credential)
    if(!(backendToken)){
      document.getElementById("feedback_div").hidden = false;
    }
    else{
      // console.log("Backend token: " + backendToken)
      setToken(backendToken);
    }
  }

  // Login to backend
  async function loginBackend(credentials){
    console.log("Login.js :: loginBackend():: Logging in with " + credentials)
    var backendToken = fetch('https://localhost:5000/api/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + credentials
        }
      }).then(data => data.json())
    console.log("Login.js :: loginBackend() :: Response is " + backendToken)
    return backendToken
  }

  // Google Login 
  useEffect(() => {
    /* global google */
    google.accounts.id.initialize({
      client_id: "xxx-yyy.apps.googleusercontent.com",
      callback: handleCallbackResponse
    });

    google.accounts.id.renderButton(
      document.getElementById("sign_in_button_google_inner"),
      { theme: "outline", size: "large" }
    )

    google.accounts.id.prompt();

  }, []);

  return(
    <div className="login_body_bg">
      <div className="login_wrapper">
          {/* User login header */}
          <div className='login_header'>
            <div className='login_header_left'>
              <p>My homepage</p>
            </div>
            <div className='login_header_right'>
              <img src="gfx/login/logo_100x49.png" alt="Advania" />
            </div>
          </div>

          {/* User login main */}
          <div className='login_main'>
            <h1>Please Log In</h1>

            {/* Feedback */}
            <div id="feedback_div" className="error_medium" style={{display: "none"}}><p className="feedback_p">Login failed</p></div>

            {/* Login form */ }
            <div id="sign_in_form_google">
              <p>Use Google to login below.</p>
              <div id="sign_in_button_google_wrapper">
                <div id="sign_in_button_google_inner"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          {/* User login footer */}
          <div class="login_footer">
            <p>&copy; 2022 My site</p>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

Login.propTypes = {
  setToken: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
```

Comment: You could use a flex box to center the button: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container

Comment: This doesnt work as the button is rendered by Google in the function "google.accounts.id.renderButton".

Comment: One option is to inspect and see what classes google is applying on the button and customise those css classes in your code to center the button. Without inspecting and looking at the DOM tree its hard to find a solution. Do you have a codesandbox link?